# Root redirects to just one subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, multisite

I want the root of my website (www.bitumephotofest.it) to redirect to a subdomain (2016.bitumephotofest.it) (I am running a Wordpress multisite). It works.

But I have another subdomain (2015.bitumephotofest.it) and it also redirects to 2016.bitumephotofest.it.

I want the redirect to work only between www.bitumephotofest.it and 2016.bitumephotofest.it. 2015.bitumephotofest.it should be independent as it is a different website.

I tried to look for questions by people with a similar situation but there is always something different and, anyway, those solutions does not work for me.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 2016.bitumephotofest.it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule !^(2016) http://2016.bitumephotofest.it [L,R]
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the domain `2015.bitumephotofest.it` stay unmodified, you can sort of exit the rewrite rule chain with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2015\.bitumephotofest\.it$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

`-` as the target means don't rewrite, see [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **- (dash)**
>   A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.